# How to initialize array in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

Very basic question :)

I have to initialize an array in objective-c. I will further use that array value in table view. I have a listing of chapters and I have written it as hardcoded like below.

```
    NSArray *tableList;

tableList = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Chapter 1",@"Chapter 2",@"Chapter 3",@"Chapter 4",@"Chapter 5",nil];
```

But now I have a indexed array which is keeping chapters details. below is the code of array which is holding value.

```
 extern NSArray *wallvalue;

    for (NSDictionary *chapter in wallvalue) {
        NSString *chapterName = [person objectForKey:@"chapters"];
        if([chapterName length] >0)
        {

            NSLog(chapterName);
        }
    }
```

Now I want to show these chapterName in my tablelist. How will I do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *tableList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[wallvalue count]];
for (NSDictionary *chapter in wallvalue) {
    NSString *chapterName = [person objectForKey:@"chapters"];
    if([chapterName length] >0)
    {
        [tableList addObject:chapterName];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Joe, Thanks for reply. But I am seeing blank on table view. I think strings are not attaching with tablelist. Please check once.

Comment: Shouldn't be empty if you were able to log the chapter name before. Something is nil somewhere, also check Deepak's edit for filtering using a predicate.

Comment: @Joe. Yes you right it was being empty. Now I am getting an exception. I think this is happening due to NULL statement.

Comment: You need to do an NSNull check on chapterName. `if(![[NSNull null] isEqual:chapterName] && [chapterName length])` of if you have control over the dictionary just dont add the key if it is going to be null.

Comment: I don't think that is the case. The predicate handles `[NSNull null]` instance.

Comment: Well +1 Somehow the predicate route failed.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you just be doing,

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[wallvalue objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"chapters"];
```

**EDIT** If you are interested in only those chapters which have a name, then filter all objects that don't have a proper name and then do the thing above,

```
NSArray * filteredChapters = [wallvalue filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"chapters LIKE '?*'"]];

[..]

cell.textLabel.text = [[filteredChapters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"chapters"];
```

Comment: Ajay is checking the length of the chapter so another array will be needed to pass the correct number of rows in the case of using a UITableView.

Comment: Yeah I updated it so that we can filter all those dictionaries that have a chapter name.

Comment: There we are gotta love predicates.

Comment: Yes Now I am getting but I am getting on excepetion which is -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe515e8
2011-06-22 19:36:20.183 FEngine[2636:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe515e8'. Is it not cheking length properly ?